# python django: pre-select dropdown of custom field

Tags: python, django

I am newbie to django python. I am trying to create CRUD using custom fields. Un update page, It shows foriegn key value instead of dropdown. Here is my code

## Model.py:

```
class RoleModel(models.Model):
    rol_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rol_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Meta:
    db_table = "tbl_roles"

def __str__(self):
    return self.rol_name

class UserModel(models.Model):
    usr_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_rolidfk = models.ForeignKey(RoleModel, blank=True, null=True, db_constraint=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usr_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    usr_email = models.EmailField() 
    usr_picture = models.FileField()
    usr_aboutme = models.TextField()
    usr_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = "tbl_users"

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user_rolidfk) + ' - ' + ', '.join([rol.rol_id for rol in self.user_rolidfk.all()])

def __unicode__(self):
    return  self.usr_name
```

## forms.py:

```
class RoleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RoleModel
        fields = "__all__"

     class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ['usr_name', 'user_rolidfk']
```

## Views.py:

```
def useredit(request, id):  
    users = UserModel.objects.get(usr_id=id) 
    roles = RoleModel.objects.all()
    form  = UserForm()
    data  = {"users": users,
             "roles": roles,
             "form": form   
            }
    return render(request,'user_edit.html', data)
```

## user_edit.html:

```
{{ users.user_rolidfk }} 
{{ form.user_rolidfk }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Modify views.py from this

```
users = UserModel.objects.get(usr_id=id)  
form = UserForm()
```

To this:

```
users = UserModel.objects.get(usr_id=id)  
form = UserForm(request.POST, instance = users)
```